# Can I use asp.net web project file in windows console c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, console-application

I am very new to windows software development. I have created a web site using VS Express 2013. It reads an xml file, connects to 4 different databases, it fetches data from these databases according to the xml file and stores the new data on a new database and displays on the screen.

The problem is: reading the data from the xml and databases must happen at the background. Users should only see the output. 
So I have decided to create a console application and use windows task scheduler which will call the console application every hour.

My question is:

Can I use the same code (asp.net web) on the c# console application without making too much changes?

At the moment I am downloading visual studio 2013 and I have got no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend of the referenced assemblies that you are using in your code but generally, if your dependances are referenced, your c# code can be used for both web and console application.

To do things right, it is better to put your code in a third-party class library that can be referenced at your choice, either in a console application startup project or a website startup project.

Comment: i have just created the console application. It was much easier  than i thought. I only changed couple of lines.